# read.csv falsly converts string to integer

Tags: r, import

I would like to read a csv file but there are columns that contain strings of digits (string variable). The values in the csv file are quoted ("") so easily identifyable as string variables but for some reason they end up as integer in my data.frame.

Here is the head of the csv

```
"task","itemnr","respnr","checked","solution","score","userid","filenr","timestamp","swmClicks","swmRT"
"swm",1,"E1","010010010","000111000",0,"77279","77279","2017-02-14T12:58:56.457+0430",3,13.0379998683929
"swm",10,"E1","011001000","011001000",1,"77279","77279","2017-02-14T13:01:50.717+0430",6,20.4059998989105
```

The problem is with the 4th and 5th column.

This is the code I use. Anything wrong with it?

```
datSwm <- read.csv("datSwm.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote='\"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

`datSwm <- read.csv("datSwm.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote='\"',colClasses=c("character","numeric","character","character","character","numeric","character","character","character","numeric","numeric"))`

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick. I hate to type all this stuff though. Typical R -_-

Comment: Yes, this is not really intuitive.

Comment: None of read.csv, read_csv or fread have an option to read the csv as it is? Typing all the stuff is really inconvenient for data with many columns...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the read.csv argument: colClasses

colClasses describes the content of the columns (see ?read.csv).

below an example for the first five columns: 
you need to drop stringAsFactors (it would be overridden by colClasses)

```
datSwm <- read.csv("datSwm.csv", header=T, quote='\"', 
colClasses = c("factor", "numeric", "character", "character", "character") )
```

You will need to add more details for the remaining columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.character()` on your two columns.

Example :

```
vec <- c(1,2,3)
> vec
[1] 1 2 3

vec <- as.character(vec)
> vec
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

So just write :

```
datSwm[,4:5] <- as.character(datSwm[,4:5])
```

Comment: No, that won't work, because leading zeros are trimmed from the import. "00110101" would turn into 110101 and as.character(110101) would be "110101". See?

Comment: @vanaoveneri Oh but you didn't put that in your statement. I think you should use the arg `ColClasses()` in that case.