# read.csv: some columns are set to zero (should be numeric but are imported as characters) in R

Tags: r, missing-data, numeric, read.csv

I am trying to import some csv files with field data to combine several csv files into one.
My goal is to have only numeric columns.

Unfortunately, R replaces all the values with "0" for some of the columns.
I do believe this is related to some missing values in the data files or columns being wrongly characters. This happens i.e. for "A", "Ca", "Ci".

When I check with the str() function, I can see that mostly the columns that were imported as characters show only zeros instead of the values in the original csv.

This is the code I'm having so far:

```
    licor6800.point_measurement.compiler<-function(){
    
      filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
      for (filename in filenames) {
        meas<-read.csv(filename, skip = 13, fileEncoding="utf-16LE", check.names=T, header = TRUE)[-1:-2,] 
        list<-cbind(filename, meas)
        list<-list%>%select("filename","date","A","Ca", "Ci","E", "CO2_s", "CO2_r", "Qin", "gsw","gtc", "Pa","Qin","RHcham","Tleaf", "PhiPS2", "Fo", "Fm", "Fv/Fm", "Adark", "Fs", "Fm",)%>%
          mutate("date" = str_split_fixed(list$date, "[:blank:](?=\\d)", 2)[,1])%>%
          mutate("date" = str_sub(date,start = 5))%>%
          mutate("Time" = str_split_fixed(list$date, "[:blank:](?=\\d)", 2)[,2])%>%
          rename("Date" = date )
      list$Date<- sub("(?<=^..)", "\\.", list$Date, perl=TRUE)
      completeA6800 <- if(exists('completeA6800') == TRUE){rbind(completeA6800, list)} else{list}
      }
      return(completeA6800)
    }
    #View(completeA6800)

str(completeA6800)
```

I tried using the as.numeric function, na.strings = "NA", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, FUN=as.numeric.

I'd be very grateful for some suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome at SO! It is great that you have provided some code. If you could provide a self-contained MRE (minimal reproducible example) with data + just the required code to reproduce the problem. This makes it easier for us help you. THX :-)

Comment: I think this kind of problem may have already been answered in another question, e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825689